# Spark Title window to Show On Top of other Title windows when clicked

Tags: flash, apache-flex, datagrid, flex4

In my application, I am using 5 buttons which will make visible(not popup) 5 different non-modal title windows.

if I click on 1st button a title window will visible and if focus is on any child components in side the opened title window, then if I open the next title window it is going back, not visible on the top of the application.

I want newly visible title window should come on top. Somebody help me

Thanks

Comment: Can you add some code as to how you are creating the popups?

Comment: only one time I'm creating the popup, after that I'm toggling visible flag for title window. no where I'm removing the popup so when the title window opens second time, its not opening on top if anyother window is already on the screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PopupManager.bringToFront() to your newly opened window.